# Why to return low, but not high in this binary search?

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates, binary-search

> Given an unsorted array nums containing n + 1 integers where each
>   integer is between 1 and n (inclusive), prove that at least one
>   duplicate number must exist. Assume that there is only one duplicate
>   number, find the duplicate one.
>
> **Note:**
>
> 1. You must not modify the array (assume the array is read only).
> 2. You must use only constant, O(1) extra space.
> 3. There is only one duplicate number in the array, but it could be repeated more than once.

For note 1, we cannot sort the array, for note 2, we cannot use hashing. I think we can use binary search here.

Suppose we have this array with duplicate number 4:

```
[1, 4(was 2), 3, 4, 5, 6, 4(was 7), 8, 9, 4]
```

The idea is we are looking at the array through a range filter (like [7,9]), 2 cases could happen:

Case 1: The range contain the duplicated element, in that case, the number of elements we can found in the filter must be larger than the number of elements it should have. For example, if we look at [3, 4], we will find 5 elements. If no duplication occurred, there should be only two [3, 4].

This is true because some other elements could rename into this group, but that cannot rename out. In this case, the expected number of element is [3, 4], but we have one extra 4 (as the duplicate) and then two 4 renamed in, that's why we have 5.

Case 2: The range does not contain the duplicated element, in that case, the number of elements we can find in the filter must be equal or less than the number of elements.

Below is my **updated** code. I wasn't sure which one to return at last line. Though I tested and found low is correct, I still don't know the reason.

```
public int findDuplicate(int[] nums) {
    int low = 1, high = nums.length - 1;
    while(low <= high){
        int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
        int count = 0;
       //count the number of elements in the filter [low,mid]
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
            if(nums[i] <= mid && nums[i]>=low){
                count++;
            }
        }
        if(count > mid-low+1){  //the duplicate would be in the left half
            high = mid;
        } else {          //the duplicate would be in the right half
            low = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return low; // Why we should return low here, not high?
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `count>=mid`? because then there would be the same number of elements in that range,as the length of the range itself, meaning no duplicates

Comment: You should be returning the duplicate *value*, not the index of the duplicate. You cannot return the index of *the* duplicate, because note 3 says that the one and only duplicate *value* may occur more than 2 times. So for your example, the duplicate value is `4`, not any of the indexes `1`, `3`, `6`, or `9`.

Comment: You can't use binary search because the array isn't sorted and you can't modify it.

Comment: when count==mid, there's no duplicate in [0,mid], since in the array has the size n+1, containing elements from 1-n, there must be at least one duplicate. @stanfordude

Comment: This is the tricky part. We cannot do Binary Search on the input array, but on the n. @JohnKugelman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear why you think you must return `low` instead of `high`. I suspect you didn't test this with many different kinds of inputs. For input 1, 1, 2, both high and low will be 0. Whether you return `high` or `low`, the answer will be incorrect.

In other words:

- the implementation doesn't solve the problem correctly, gives incorrect result
- the question "to return lie or high" is the wrong question to ask

The explanation of your algorithm sounds about right. The problem is, you haven't actually implemented what you explained there. You talk about counting elements within a range, adjusting the lower and upper bounds of the range as you go, but in your implementation, you count `nums[I] <= mid`, so only the upper bound changes (`mid`), the lower bound is always (implicitly) 0. This doesn't match your explanation. You did not implement your idea correctly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out! I've corrected the code. It counts `nums[i] <= mid && nums[i]>=low` now